# redmine installation fail ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, redmine

I got error while installing redmine on ubuntu 14.04. I don't understand why I get this error.
Below is are stack I get

```
apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
redmine is already the newest version.
redmine-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up redmine (2.4.2-1) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/redmine/instances/defaul
t.conf

Creating config file /etc/redmine/default/database.yml.new with new version
granting access to database redmine_default for redmine_default@localhost: alrea
dy exists.
creating database redmine_default: already exists.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
Replacing config file /etc/redmine/default/session.yml with new version
A new secret session key has been generated in /etc/redmine/default/session.yml
Populating database for redmine instance "default".
This may take a while.
rake aborted!
Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'redmine_default'@'localhost' has a
password in the old format; please change the password to the new format
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Error when running rake db:migrate, check database configuration.
dpkg: error processing package redmine (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Errors were encountered while processing: redmine

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

Following is output of command dpkg -l redmine

```
`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
iF  redmine        2.4.2-1      all          flexible project management web a`
```

Rails version install on my machine
    `rails -v
    Rails 4.1.4`

Ruby version install on my machine
    `ruby -v
    ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]`

apache2 version

```
`apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2014 12:20:28`
```

I am new to ubuntu and also linux. Can anyone identify why I get this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way the password is being passed to the MySQL server.

You can set secure_auth: true in the database.yml file right under where the password is specified to use the appropriate format.

Alternatively, you could disable secure auth in the mysql daemon config and restart.

Comment: is it mean it restart mysql ? Is it possible to do it without restarting mysql ? Because some of the application run on my machine which use mysql, so I can't stop it. and for your information if this is the problem then why it allow to create database ? means I found there is redmine_default database is created with this process.Thanks for quick reply.